# Does SQL Anywhere version 10 works with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sqlanywhere

I see Sybase SQL Anywhere has Entity Framework provider for version 11 and 12, but I want to get it working with SQL Anywhere 10. Is it possible. Upgrading to version 11 or 12 is not possible in our environment, so we must stick to version 10. Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

One way to get EF working with SQL Anywhere 10 is to install sybase sql anywhere developer edition 
11 or 12 and use the **client** (that supports EF) to access Sql Anywhere 10 database. This workaround works because the client has backward compatibility.but before you do anything check the license agreement for redistributing the client.